# In Python the shutil.copy command makes the copy of the file read only

Tags: python

I'm a Python noob and only use it to writes small scripts to automate repetitive tasks.

This line of code is in one of my scripts.  It works fine, but the new `.xlsx` file is read only.  That's a minor inconvenience until I try to write to it from a different script.

```
shutil.copy("C:\\Users\\raymond.kirchner\\OneDrive - RIVER CITY MORTGAGE\\MY RCM\\Tools\\Choppa worksheet V5.xlsx" , newFolder+"\\"+str(lastName)+" Choppa  V5.xlsx")
```

Is there a method to change the permissions on the copy?

Comment: Have you checked administrative privilege's allowance? Check them for both: the platform; and the file.

Comment: I'll need to research that.  In the same script, I run the same code for a Word file and that works fine.

Comment: `shutil.copy` copies the "mode" bits, so if the original file was marked "read-only", the new copy will be as well.  You can change that with `os.chmod`.  Note, however, that the office apps consider any file downloaded from email or web to be dangerous, and will show it as read-only even if the file itself is not.  Is that the case here?

Comment: Both the Excel file and Word file I am copying are from the same directory.  But only the Excel file copy is Read Only, the Word file is fine.

Comment: And neither file is Read Only in the source directory

Comment: SOLVED: I had no idea the original file was read only because I alway copied and pasted.  I saved as a new file name and it works.